# How to show that for $P$ weakly prime ideal, if $\sqrt{0} \subsetneq P$, then $P$ is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In D. D. Anderson and Eric Smith, *Weakly prime ideals*, **2003**. $R$ is commutative ring with identity

There is a theorem:

"Let $P$ be a weakly prime ideal of $R$. If $P$ is not prime, then $P^2=0$"

And then there is a Corollary:

"Let $P$ be a weakly prime ideal of $R$. Then $P \subseteq \sqrt{0}$ or $\sqrt{0} \subseteq P$. If $P \subsetneq \sqrt{0}$ then $P$ is not prime; while if $\sqrt{0} \subsetneq P$ then $P$ is prime"

I've try to proof this, but i'm stuck here.

we have $\sqrt{0}=\{r\in R \mid r^n\in 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \}$

by the corollary (i mean is to proof "if $\sqrt{0} \subsetneq P$ then $P$ is prime"), my idea is:

"if we take whenever $x \in \sqrt{0}$, then $x \in P$ but there is $y \in P$, $y \notin \sqrt{0}$. In other word, there is $y \in P$ which $y$ is not nilpoten"

until here, i think i must show that $P^2 \neq 0$ (this is accord the theorem that when $P^2 \neq 0$, $P$ is prime)

i'm stuck here, how to show that always $P^2 \neq 0$ for this condition?

I'm attaching the picture of the corollary, maybe you need it

[Theorem & Corollary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTZzM.png)

i hope, you can help me. Thank You very much

*I'm sorry if my english is so bad, but i will always try to be better*

Comment: i have idea that, suppose that $P^2=0$ so for whenever $p \in P$, $p^2=0$. This is contradiction that there is $y \in P$, $y$ is not nilpotent. So must be $P^2\neq 0$. is this idea can i use to proof this condition. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is prime then clearly $\sqrt{0}\subseteq P$. If $P$ is not prime then we have $P^2=0$, and so:

$P\subseteq\sqrt{P^2}=\sqrt{0}$

This gives you everything you need. If $\sqrt{0}\subsetneq P$ then $P$ must be prime. (because if it wasn't then we would have $P\subseteq\sqrt{0}$, as we have shown)